# Can I dual boot Linux Mint 32/64?

Tags: system-installation

I have Linux Mint Maya 13 XFCE 4, 64bit installed on my pc.
I can't download Swedish bankid on a 64bit version.

Is it possible to make a dual boot by installing a 32bit version and keeping my 64 bit as it is today?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to make it dual boot, see [here.](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=122296)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.